# Weighted logistic regression for complex survey design

Tags: logistic, survey-weights

I want to run a logistic regression on my dataset in R. I want to test the probability of which direction a fish is facing depending on my variables. I am considering using a weighted logistic regression since my data come from a complex survey design where there could be a possible lack of independence. My concerns come from nets located near another (possibly recapturing individuals) or some nets may catch more fish due to schooling behavior (species). I am searching for advice on how to weigh these observations.

Dependent variable: Direction fish is facing in net (1: out; 0: in)
Independent variables: Month, Year, Depth, Time Period, Site (all variables are categorical)

```
> summary(ALE)
```

```
  Sample_ID           Year           Month     Site        DepthCat   TimePeriodCalc Species  
 Length:993         2011:887   August   :141   3S:228   Deep   :549   Morning:591    ALE:993  
 Class :character   2013:106   July     :623   4S:765   Mid    :426   Day    :112    STS:  0  
 Mode  :character              June     :120            Shallow: 18   Evening:290    YEP:  0  
                               May      : 87                                                  
                               September: 22                                                  
 Direction
 0:284    
 1:709
```

Comment: Hi @Dominique, welcome to CV. How familiar are you with survey design? For example, to develop weights, it has to be a probability-based sample (e.g. from a list frame, or an area sample), you start defining weights with the inverse probability of selection. Potentially a second option, depending on the design, is using a generalised linear mixed effects model, where the mixed effect could be site etc.

Comment: Hi @Alex! I am not familiar with survey design. I was reading "Modeling Binary Correlated Responses using SAS, SPSS and R" (Wilson and Lorenz 2015; DOI 10.1007/978-3-319-23805-0) which mentioned that complex survey designs from stratification, clustering, and/or unequal weighting could cause a lack of independence and weighting should be considered. Ultimately, I want to see if fish move into shore or off shore during a certain time of day based on my variables.

Comment: I suspect that survey analysis is not appropriate for your data. Potential clustering effects could be addressed by using a "mixed effects" model. To help me, could you please add to your question how your data collection was designed?